# Can I merge my contacts list on two Gmail accounts?

Tags: gmail, google-contacts

I have two Gmail accounts.  My main email account and one that was set up by a Sprint employee when I first purchased my smartphone.

Is there a way I can merge the contact lists I have on both accounts so that I don't have to retype everything into one account?

Answer (score 6):

The easiest solution for you would probably be to export the contacts from one account and then add them to the other. If you've already put some contacts into the new account then you can [merge the duplicates](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=165334&cbid=-1gme1cgakrp51&src=cb&lev=%20answer) that are generated.

To export, just go to your contacts and in the More Actions dropdown select "Export...". Use the Google CSV format since you'll just be re-importing them, save to your desktop, then go to the same place in your new account and select "Import...". You may lose some information such as group membership but it's much better than having to re-enter all of your contact information.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Gmail Delegation](http://www.businessinsider.com/how-to-merge-multiple-gmail-addresses-in-one-account-2010-12?op=1) feature. Unfortunately or luckily, this feature works only within the same domain.